# Apache Solr 6.6.1 number mapping in Urdu language

Tags: java, apache, solr, lucene, tokenize

I have configured Apache Solr 6.6.2 to index and search documents later. I am facing some problems. If there is a number in document like 1234, I want it should be mapped (copied) to corresponding Urdu numerics like ۱۲۳۴. It will ultimately help to retrieve document if either user enter 1234 or ۱۲۳۴.
Is there any built in solution in Solr or how I can come into this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java/SolrJ client for indexing ...

Add junidecode dependency to your project

for gradle

```
compile group: 'junidecode', name: 'junidecode', version: '0.1.1'
```

for maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junidecode</groupId>
    <artifactId>junidecode</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

while indexing ... index an additional field ...

```
import net.sf.junidecode.Junidecode;
String converted = Junidecode.unidecode("۱۲۳۴") 
// converted == 1234
```

Comment: Thanks for reply; my question is how to customize Solr for number mapping. My idea is that I have to write some tokenizer to do this but I am not confirm till now

Comment: Can you please tell me how you are indexing the data, Is it through SolrJ client or is data is in static json/xml format. 
The idea is that you need to add an additional convereted (ascified) data in the filed or text field, 
whether you modify data before posting it to solr or through writing a solr filter etc.
You migh also want to check: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-ASCIIFoldingFilter

Comment: I am indexing data via post.sh script and data in XML

Comment: did you try ASCIIFoldingFilter?